# Is "the" pronounced as "thuh" or "thee" in this sentence

Tags: pronunciation

"the amount of fun"

Is "the" pronounced as "thee" before a schwa?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are trying to speak U.S. English or U.K. english. But both are correct.

Comment: . . . and different people, both in the US and the UK, pronounce it differently. Saying that one pronunciation is used in the US and the other in the UK is very much a generalization.

Comment: ...True...but strictly speaking I was referring to the standard, ie taught, or received, pronounciatian for the USA and UK respectively not individual regional and or personal dialects.

Comment: [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/the) gives three different pronunciations but nothing prescriptive. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the) gives two pronunciations and mentions which are commonly used in the US. But it says nothing prescriptive. I am quite sure that I was never told about any rule of pronunciation when I was in school. It was simply learning from listening—and different people pronounced it differently. There is no ruling body of pronunciation. It's a language learner myth—as stated in the duplicated question.

Comment: There nott only is, but it is taught to newscasters and reporters while going through journilism school, it is how and why newscasters all sound the same.   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_English